# Aborting a Task which internally creates a new Thread causes an UnhandledException

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I'm trying to abort a task which internally creates a thread.
The problem is that the inner thread is trying to access a resource which is already disposed (since the parent task is already cancelled), and that causes an unhandled exception.

The code which creates the thread is a 'black box', an external DLL, so I cannot pass it a CancellationToken or so.

What can I do to make the task abort its inner threads? Or what is the solution for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: The threads in TPL managed by scheduler, and it gets threads from pool. If your task creates new thread intrnallyyour "black box" must provide API for managing/controlling its threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't manage the threads yourself then the best you can do is handle the exception. Throw a try catch aound the black box call and respond appropriately in your own code.

If you can I'd be complaining to the provider of the black box though.  They should give you the proper api for using their tools.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a timeout - I'm willing to stop the program after a certain amount of time. In order to achieve it I execute the program in a different Task, then stop it from the main thread. Is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: If you run it on another task you can call task.Wait(timespan) and it will timeout after a certain period.